# Rails 3, adding joins to default_scope for association of current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

In my app i have a schema of Users and Tickets, each User can be subscribed to many Tickets and viceversa.

For each ticket i fetch from the database, i want to display if current_user is subscribed or not to the ticket itself.

An example of my query is as follows:

```
@tickets = current_user.tickets.limit(10).order('created_at DESC')
```

Can i do it using a default_scope with a join in Ticket model?, i need it to return an additional field with a simple true or false, or nil.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example 1** - To figure out whether an individual ticket is subscribed:

```
ticket = Ticket.find(id)
@ticket_is_subscribed = current_user.tickets.any? { |t| t == ticket }
```

**Example 2** - If you want simply an array with all ticket IDs subscribed by the current user:

```
subscribed_ids = current_user.tickets.pluck(:id)
@ticket_is_subscribed = subscribed_ids.include?(ticket.id)
```

**Example 3** - You could generate an array of arrays that gives you `true` or `false` for each `ticket.id`.

```
subscribed_ids = current_user.tickets.pluck(:id)
@all_subscribed_tickets = Ticket.all.pluck(:id).map { |id| [id, subscribed_ids.include?(id)] }
```

Comment: Thank you depa, but, is that efficient? What if i fetch a thousand tickets, it would do, in the worst case, the squared 1000 comparisons?

Comment: Check the second example with `pluck`.

Comment: I think the most efficient way would be dealing with arrays as much as you can, rather than ActiveRecord collections. So you could, for instance, generate an array of arrays that gives you `true` or `false` for each `ticket.id`.

Comment: Thank you depa, your new example with pluck is perfect for my purpose, i've donde something similar in another system with php but as i'm learning rails since not so long ago my head was filled with stuff and couldn't remember

Comment: Yeah, `pluck` is very nice to extract collections into arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague so I imagine the case is you fetch a bunch of tickets and show if current user have it. If having, show "yes", else show "now".

You can have a model method in Ticket to judge it.

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  def is_buyer?(buyer)
    user == buyer ? "yes" : "no"
  end
end

# In controller
@tickets = Ticket.page(1)

# In view
- @tickets.each do |ticket|
  = ticket.name
  = ticket.is_buyer?(current_user)
```